# Find the Max value of an Array column and find associated value in another Array with in the dataframe

Tags: arrays, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a csv file with below data.

| Id | Subject | Marks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | M,P,C | 10,8,6 |
| 2 | M,P,C | 5,7,9 |
| 3 | M,P,C | 6,7,4 |

I Need to find out Max value in the Marks column for each Id and find the Associate subject from the subject column.

My desired result should be:

| Id | Subject | Marks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | M | 10 |
| 2 | C | 9 |
| 3 | P | 7 |

I am reading the csv file and make the Subject & Marks as Array column using comma value split.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

 val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    
    val df = spark.read.format("CSV")
                  .option("header", "true")
                  .option("delimiter", "|")
                  .option("inferSchema", "true")
                  .load("file:///p:/test/Data/test.csv")

   val df1 = df.select(col("id"),
                        split(col("subjects"),",").as("subjects"),
                        split(col("Makrs"),",").as("Makrs")
                      )

   df1.printSchema()
```

df1 schema is:

```
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Sub: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- Mark: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

And df1 data is;

```
+---+---------+----------+
| id| subjects|     Makrs|
+---+---------+----------+
|  1|[M, P, C]|[10, 8, 6]|
|  2|[M, P, C]| [5, 7, 9]|
|  3|[M, P, C]| [6, 7, 4]|
+---+---------+----------+
```

I Am stuck how to find the Max value in Array column in a dataframe.

I tried [array_max](https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/arraytype-columns/) but getting an error that  ***not found: value array_max***

`df1.withColumn("MaxMarks", array_max($"Makrs")).show()`

Comment: take a look to the array_max function: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_max

Comment: @EmilianoMartinez Thank you for your response. I have tried array_max function from the source https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/arraytype-columns/ . But getting an error that  ```not found: value array_max```

Comment: what version of Spark are you using?

Comment: @EmilianoMartinez Sorry for the dealy. Using Spark Version 2.3.0

Comment: I think that the array ops are available from 2.4. So you have to use an UDF

Answer (score 0):

If you strongly type your Dataframe to a Dataset whose types you control, you can use a `map` function quite easily. You'll just need to define a case class + encoder to make this possible.

I made a very simple csv file with the following exact content (Your data):

```
Id;Subject;Marks
1;M,P,C;10,8,6
2;M,P,C;5,7,9
3;M,P,C;6,7,4
```

And the code looks something like this (most of it is just reading the data in properly):

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders

case class MyClass(Id: Int, Subject: Seq[String], Marks: Seq[Int])
implicit val myEncoder = Encoders.product[MyClass]

val df = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("sep", ";").csv("csvWithArrays.csv")

val parsedDF = df
  .withColumn("Id", col("Id").cast("int"))
  .withColumn("Subject", split(col("Subject"), ","))
  .withColumn("Marks", split(col("Marks"), ",").cast("array<int>"))
  .as[MyClass]

val output = parsedDF.map{
  case MyClass(id, subject, marks) => {
    val maxMark = marks.max
    val maxSubject = subject(marks.indices.maxBy(marks))
    (id, maxSubject, maxMark) 
  }
}

output.show                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
+---+---+---+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
| _1| _2| _3|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
+---+---+---+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
|  1|  M| 10|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
|  2|  C|  9|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
|  3|  P|  7|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
+---+---+---+
```

Once you have strongly typed your Dataset you can easily make use of the Scala language to get exactly what you want :)

Hope this helps!